# Showing $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_{i} v_i^* (T(v_i))$ for a linear map $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T:V  \rightarrow V$ be a linear map. Let $\{v_i\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{v_i^*\}$ is a basis of $V^*$, dual space of $V$. Then I want to show
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_i v_i^* (T(v_i)). 
\end{align}

---

I am familiar with the trace of a linear map as $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \langle v_i, T(v_i) \rangle$ and it seems the above formula is somehow the rigorous extension of this. But anyway it was something like given not proven.....

I know for the linear map $T$, $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \operatorname{tr}([T]_{\beta})$ but does not understand which step the dual basis comes out.

I found some posts from StackExchange

[$T$ is a linear operator on a IPS $V$ which has a basis $\beta$. Prove that $A_{ij} = \langle T(v_j),v_i \rangle$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712695/t-is-a-linear-operator-on-a-ips-v-which-has-a-basis-beta-prove-that-a)

[The trace formula of a linear map $T: V \to V$, $\operatorname{tr}(T) = \sum_k (Te_k,e_k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137077/the-trace-formula-of-a-linear-map-t-v-to-v-operatornametrt-sum-k?rq=1)

and for each case, the dual basis does not come out.  Naively I guess there is a relation, but I want to know explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean that $v_i^*$ is specifically the dual basis of the $v_i$? Because it's clearly false that you can pick the bases of $V$ and $V^*$ independently. Just consider the inner-product space case and let $T(v)=v$ and $v_{i}^*=\langle v_{i+1},\cdot\rangle$ with the index counted mod $\dim(V)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, I mean $v_i^*$ is a dual basis of $v_i$. i.e., $\langle v_i^*, v_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $T(v_i) = \sum_{j}k_{ij}v_j$. Note that $k_{ij} = v_{j}^{*}(T(v_i))$. In fact

$$v_{j}^{*}(T(v_i)) = v_{j}^{*}( \sum_{l}k_{il}v_l ) = \sum_{l}k_{il}v_{j}^{*}(v_l)= k_{ij} .$$

Then $T(v_i) = \sum_{j}v_{j}^{*}(T(v_i))v_j$. Now just write the $T$ matrix and take the Trace operator, you will see that it is exactly $\sum_{j}v_{j}^{*}(T(v_j))$.

Answer (score 1):

The linear maps $T_{ij}=v_iv_j^*$ form a basis of $\mathrm {End}V$. The matrix representation of $T_{ij}$ with respect to the basis $v$ contains a $1$ at position $ij$ and is zero otherwise. Hence $\operatorname{tr}(T_{ij})=\partial_{ij}$.

Now the formula you want to show holds true for the $T_{ij}$ and hence by linearity for all $T\in\mathrm {End}V$.